# How to programmatically retrieve the equivalent of the "name" field in microsoft's inspect.exe?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I want to retrieve information from a tooltip in the system tray programmatically.

[image: This shows the tooltip I'm talking about]

The image shows the tooltip.

Now, I found that by using Microsoft's inspect.exe, which is *"a Windows-based tool that enables you select any UI element and view the element's accessibility data"*, that it is in theory possible to retrieve this value programmatically.

Hovering over the the pandora icon in the toolbar shows me the following properties

[image: Properties of the pandora icon control as shown by inspect.exe]

It shows one property "name" that contains the exact data I need. I'm unsure how to retrieve this value programmatically using the win32api. I have a hwnd to the pandora icon already.

Additionally, a different ui spy tool, UiSpy.exe calls this same property "helpText" (different song name :p)

[image]

I tried using `getWindowText(pandoraSystrayIconHwnd)` but that returns a different text. Does anyone know what this "name" value is, and how I can retrieve it using the win32api? It should be possible because inspect.exe is an external program that can access the data *somehow*

I'm doing this in Python, as the target application is written in Python already.

Comment: Are you only interested in the currently playing song?

Comment: @andlabs in the end, yes

Comment: Then the "other alternatives" links in @Anders's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

These spy apps are probably using [Active Accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility) and/or [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation).

You can try calling [AccessibleObjectFromWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx) on the toolbar HWND or [AccessibleObjectFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317977(v=vs.85).aspx) if you care about the mouse position and then call [IAccessible::get_accName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318483(v=vs.85).aspx).

Keep in mind that the classname and window hierarchy of the tray icon toolbar is undocumented.

If you only care about Pandora and not other applications then I would strongly suggest that you look for [other](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/json/) [alternatives](https://developer.pandora.com/) first. Perhaps they have a hidden window with the title etc.

If you don't mind hacks then you could take a look at [TraySaver](https://web.archive.org/web/20060415144446/http://www.mlin.net/TraySaver.shtml), it is open source and knows the internal format of the data stored for each icon in the tray toolbar. Keep in mind that it is pretty old and might not work on newer versions of Windows. If you go down this path (and I don't recommend it) then you have to remember that you need to support both 32-bit and 64-bit Explorer.

Comment: The [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool can be configured to use *Microsoft Active Accesibility* or the newer *UI Automation* interfaces. The combo box in the top left is used to toggle between both modes.

Comment: The properties I am interested turn out to be accessible using UI Automation, I came really close with MSAA. I opted to go for the hacky way, because I'm interested in reading from more than one application in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe GUI automation library [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) could help you. It uses Win32 API or UI Automation under the hood (by your choice). Core concept is described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Method `.window_text()` returns exactly the same as `Name` property shows in Inspect.exe.

To interact with tray area icons you can use [this example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29631404/3648361).